# Trigger custom event when updating/deleting from room dao

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

i would like to know if it is possible to trigger a custom event when a method on a room dao is called. In my particular case i want to remove a file after the entity referencing that file is being deleted. I have an entity called `Picture` that holds a path to the actual file on disk. When an entity of `Picture` is deleted from the database i need to remove the file as well if it was saved by the app / in the app directory. After quite some research i could not find anything that fits my needs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i would like to know if it is possible to trigger a custom event when a method on a room dao is called

No, sorry.

> When an entity of Picture is deleted from the database i need to remove the file as well if it was saved by the app / in the app directory

Whatever code of yours calls the `@Delete` method on the DAO is responsible for deleting the file.

Comment: i already expected that :/ looks like i need to build a wrapper for this... thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

In room any method annotated in your dao with @Delete annotation will return "int" 0 if no item is deleted or return total number of row deleted.

you can do something like this.

```
if(yourDB.getYourDao.delete()>0){

    //Do task you want to perform on deletion.
}
```